# Redirecting Appspot URL to custom domain

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect, app.yaml

I deployed a website (it consists of one index.html page and folders that contain js, image & css files)  on the app-engine and linked it to my custom domain. I configured the CNAME and the site is opening on my domain, but the original appspot URL is not being redirected to the custom domain.

I did come across pages with similar questions which discussed about this problem. I tried implementing those, but they didn't seem to work.

Here is what I did, in the **app.yaml** file I replaced:

```
- url: /.*
  static_files: static
  upload: static
```

with

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.application
```

and in the **main.py**, I erased all the content and added the following:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/', webapp2.RedirectHandler, defaults={'_uri':'http://subdomain.domain.com}),
], debug=False)

def main():
    application.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(Modified code after suggestions by Jeff)

But it doesn't seem to work. The appspot URL is not being redirected but my custom domain is working alright. What changes should I make in the above code to make the redirection possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **application** variable is not doing anything if that is the entire contents of your main.py file.

Add the following to bottom of main.py:

```
def main():
    application.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also you probably don't need AllHandler since the route is redirecting everything.

Comment: Thank you for the rectification. But even after the changes being made, redirection is not happening.

Comment: I tried adding the following code as well, still didn't work:

`def get(self):
        if os.environ['HTTP_HOST'].endswith('.appspot.com'):
            self.redirect('http://example.com')`

Kindly help.